# Batchfile: What's the best way to declare and use a boolean variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-10, command-prompt

What's the best way to declare and use a boolean variable in Batch files? This is what I'm doing now:

```
set "condition=true"

:: Some code that may change the condition

if %condition% == true (
    :: Some work
)
```

Is there a better, more "formal" way to do this? (e.g. In Bash you can just do `if $condition` since `true` and `false` are commands of their own.)

Comment: That's pretty much it. Variables in batch are either strings or 32-bit integers and nothing else.

Comment: You could do `if defined var`, which gives the benefit of working within `if`, `for`, and other parenthetical code blocks without requiring delayed expansion.  There's also conditional execution based on zero or non-zero errorlevel.

Comment: shouldn't it be "%condition%"=="true" ?

Comment: @svasa - if `%condition%` can be guaranteed to have a value, you don't need them; the quotes are just to avoid a syntax error if it's empty.

Comment: @SomethingDark: All variables are strings; there are not numeric variables in Batch files. The arithmetic operations performed by `set /A` command just manage 32-bits integers, but that is not exactly the same thing...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm sticking with my original answer for the time being:

```
set "condition=true"

:: Some code...

if "%condition%" == "true" (
    %= Do something... =%
)
```

If anyone knows of a better way to do this, please answer this question and I'll gladly accept your answer.

Comment: The answer of Magoo is better, as it also works inside of code blocks

Comment: I imagine that the magoo one is faster to execute because it does not compare strings and it is the closest thing to what they do in another programming language with booleam. Example: C(Everything that is not 0 is true), batch(Everything with value is true)

Answer (score 43):

```
set "condition="
```

and

```
set "condition=y"
```

where `y` could be any string or numeric.

This allows `if defined` and `if not defined` both of which can be used within a block statement (a parenthesised sequence of statements) to interrogate the run-time status of the flag without needing `enabledelayedexpansion`

---

ie.

```
set "condition="
if defined condition (echo true) else (echo false)

set "condition=y"
if defined condition (echo true) else (echo false)
```

The first will echo `false`, the second `true`

Comment: @AlexanderSchäl : More explanation. `%condition%` refers to the *contents* of the variable `condition`, so `if defined %condition%` is enterpreted as `if defined y` if `condition` has the value `y`

Answer (score 7):

I suppose another option would be to use "1==1" as a truth value.

Thus repeating the example:

```
set condition=1==1

:: some code

if %condition% (
    %= Do something... =%
)
```

Of course it would be possible to set some variables to hold `true` and `false` values:

```
set true=1==1
set false=1==0

set condition=%true%

:: some code

if %condition% (
    %= Do something... =%
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. I suspect that trying to include quotes complicates things, but the quotes are probably not necessary when the value assigned does not have any whitespace.

```
set condition=true

:: Some code that may change the condition
set condition=false

if %condition%==true (
    :: Some work
) ELSE (
    :: Do something else
)
```