# How to remove spaces in the File name of the text file?

Tags: batch-file, scripting

The file is not added in the destination path if it has spaces in the file name.

For example, if the filename is textfile1.txt -> it will be added in the destination path. However, if the directory filename has space like this text file4.txt it will not be added.

Is there a way to remove the spaces of the filename?
Here is the image:

[image: Kindly check the image here]

Here is my main concern:

[image: Check this]

Here is my script:

```
@ECHO off
TITLE (c) ASDG 
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET locationPath=C:\Textfiles\
SET destinationPath=E:\Textfiles\
SET status=success
SET countMetadata=0
SET countPDF=0
SET countJPEG=0

ECHO Executing the program...
FOR /R %locationPath% %%g IN (*.txt) DO (
    CD %%~dpg
    IF EXIST *.txt* (
        FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1* delims=|" %%a IN (%%~nxg) DO (
            SET /a countMetadata+=1
            ECHO %%~dpa%%a^| %%b >> %destinationPath%^%%~nxg
        )
        IF %status% == success (
            ECHO %%g has been successfully added
            ECHO %%g >> %destinationPath%^logs.txt
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Add `""` to wrap the entire file path, if you fave `text file4.txt` , use `type "text file4.txt"`, add `"` wrap file path. change `IF EXIST %destinationPath%\merge.txt` to `IF EXIST "%destinationPath%\merge.txt" `

Comment: I tried this sir, but it does not work

Comment: Can you try this Sir Ken? `ECHO %%~dpa%%a^| %%b >> %destinationPath%^"%%~nxg"`
The file name that has space does not add to the destination path.

Comment: It should be `"%destinationPath%%%~nxg"`

Comment: I also tried that Sir Ken. But it does not work

Comment: Sir @KenWhite can we have a session? I'll show you my script

Comment: You need to use double quotes on your variables and when using `set` (excluding `set /a`), but why on earth are you escaping  the pipes in the code blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reformatting to use indentation to show `code blocks` (parenthesised code that is parsed, substituting `%variables%`, then executed), I then applied various recommendations:

Use `set "var=value"` for setting **string** values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Don't assign `"` or a terminal backslash or Space. Build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier. If the syntax `set var="value"` is used, then the quotes become part of the value assigned.

Use `set /a` to assign numeric values. No quotes required.

***THIS CODE WILL NOT FULLY PERFORM THE REQUIRED TASK***

Without comments to explain why some code is used, it's difficult to provide guidance.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
TITLE (c) ASDG 

SET "locationPath=C:\Textfiles"
SET "destinationPath=E:\Textfiles"


SET "status=success"
SET /a countMetadata=0
SET /a countPDF=0
SET /a countJPEG=0


ECHO Executing the program...
FOR /R "%locationPath%" %%g IN (*.txt) DO (
 CD %%~dpg

 IF EXIST *.txt* (
  FOR /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1* delims=|" %%a IN ("%%~nxg") DO (
   SET /a countMetadata+=1

   ECHO %%~dpa%%a^| %%b >> %destinationPath%\%%~nxg
  )
  IF !status! == success (
   ECHO %%g has been successfully added
   ECHO %%g >> %destinationPath%\logs.txt
  )
 )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Modifications explanation

I prefer the `setlocal` to be the second line. YMMV.

`Set` commands modified as explained above

`locationpath` in the `for /R` quoted - it may contain separators like spaces.

`%%~nxg` quoted in `for...%%a` as it may contain spaces

`usebackq` added to `for...%%a` as `%%~nxg` is now quoted

```
I prefer to avoid ADFNPSTXZ (in either case) as metavariables (loop-control variables) 
ADFNPSTXZ are also metavariable-modifiers which can lead to difficult-to-find bugs 
(See `for/f` from the prompt for documentation)
```

Not sure what is going on with the following `echo`, but `destinationPath` no longer has the terminal `\`. Same comment applies to the following `ECHO %%g`.

`!staus!` replaces `%status%` (logically) as logically, `status` may change within the block - the [delayed expansion trap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947)

***BUT*** `status` is not being varied within the block, so its value will always be its initial value, `success`.

[Using Boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35545602/2128947)

So - a few things for OP to clean up...