# How to filter out the line which counting up from last line from a text file thru batch command?

Tags: batch-file, filter, line

I've wrote a batch script that to capture a specific location string from a text file, for example:

The text file contains:

```
Copyright Version 5.39
Network activity progressing...


Thread  Time(s) Throughput(KB/s) Avg B / Compl
======  ======= ================ =============
     0  600.088        73245.829     45502.632
     1  594.574        84312.667     44974.835
     2  594.569        62862.184     44547.486
     3  599.665        66407.148     45056.270
     4  600.633        61846.742     44741.495
     5  594.569        45967.918     46745.891
     6  594.937        72678.901     45115.861
     7  593.981        86081.374     45148.288
     8  593.975        35448.661     44118.093
     9  602.451        64144.439     44708.118
    10  599.760        26404.342     53411.916
    11  594.569        64959.044     44525.327
    12  594.564        63125.969     44512.966
    13  602.999        71045.335     45266.114
    14  599.719        19782.849     54192.569
    15  594.574        61670.399     44341.198
    16  599.681        71804.247     44954.492
    17  593.980        21731.533     43903.776
    18  593.979        22436.796     43919.327
    19  599.748        21296.983     53880.446


#####  Totals:  #####


   Bytes(MEG)    realtime(s) Avg Frame Size Throughput(MB/s)
================ =========== ============== ================
   639903.106318     600.002       4289.297         1066.502


Throughput(Buffers/s) Cycles/Byte       Buffers
===================== =========== =============
            17064.032      41.043  10238449.701


DPCs(count/s) Pkts(num/DPC)   Intr(count/s) Pkts(num/intr)
============= ============= =============== ==============
  3081479.450         0.085     2302796.649          0.113


Packets Sent Packets Received Retransmits Errors Avg. CPU %
============ ================ =========== ====== ==========
    66199455        156432871           4      0     99.998
```

There are total 58 lines in the text file, and I will need to get `Throughput(MB/s)` value, which allocated in line 43, and the 4th string, from above example it is `1066.502`.

So, I created a batch script to filter out the number:

```
set "lom1="
for /f "skip=48 delims=" %%i in LOM_1.log) do if not defined lom1 set "lom1=%%i"
echo !lom1! >> temp1.txt
for /f "tokens=4" %%j in temp1.txt do echo %%j >> result.log
```

But, now the source text got errors and it increases random lines, for example:

```
Copyright Version 5.39
Network activity progressing...
ERROR: WaitForWorkerThreads failed: WaitForMultipleObjects returned an unexpected value

ERROR: DoWork failed: WaitForWorkerThreads(threads_finished) timed out
ERROR: StartSenderReceiver in thread: 9 failed: closesocket, GetLastError: 10093 - Either the application has not called WSAStartup, or WSAStartup failed.

ERROR: StartSenderReceiver in thread: 13 failed: closesocket, GetLastError: 10093 - Either the application has not called WSAStartup, or WSAStartup failed.

ERROR: StartSenderReceiver in thread: 16 failed: closesocket, GetLastError: 10093 - Either the application has not called WSAStartup, or WSAStartup failed.



Thread  Time(s) Throughput(KB/s) Avg B / Compl
======  ======= ================ =============
     0  600.088        73245.829     45502.632
     1  594.574        84312.667     44974.835
     2  594.569        62862.184     44547.486
     3  599.665        66407.148     45056.270
     4  600.633        61846.742     44741.495
     5  594.569        45967.918     46745.891
     6  594.937        72678.901     45115.861
     7  593.981        86081.374     45148.288
     8  593.975        35448.661     44118.093
     9  602.451        64144.439     44708.118
    10  599.760        26404.342     53411.916
    11  594.569        64959.044     44525.327
    12  594.564        63125.969     44512.966
    13  602.999        71045.335     45266.114
    14  599.719        19782.849     54192.569
    15  594.574        61670.399     44341.198
    16  599.681        71804.247     44954.492
    17  593.980        21731.533     43903.776
    18  593.979        22436.796     43919.327
    19  599.748        21296.983     53880.446


#####  Totals:  #####


   Bytes(MEG)    realtime(s) Avg Frame Size Throughput(MB/s)
================ =========== ============== ================
   639903.106318     600.002       4289.297         1066.502


Throughput(Buffers/s) Cycles/Byte       Buffers
===================== =========== =============
            17064.032      41.043  10238449.701


DPCs(count/s) Pkts(num/DPC)   Intr(count/s) Pkts(num/intr)
============= ============= =============== ==============
  3081479.450         0.085     2302796.649          0.113


Packets Sent Packets Received Retransmits Errors Avg. CPU %
============ ================ =========== ====== ==========
    66199455        156432871           4      0     99.998
```

You can see that there are additional `ERROR` lines in the text file, that means I cannot still use the `for /f "skip=48"` command to filter the right line out, so, I'd like to know, if any batch command or `for /f` parameters can be used to count up from last line so that it will be always fix line number, for example on above text content, if I count up from last line and the 16<sup>th</sup> line is what I want, then I can keep to export the 16<sup>th</sup> line (count from the last line), then to capture the 4<sup>th</sup> string for the number.

I tried to google but cannot find useful information.

Comment: I would approach this by simply using a `for /f`` loop on the output of a `findstr` which ignores lines containing `=`, [Using a Boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35545602/2128947) to detect whether the fourth token of the line is `Throughput(MB/s)` and when that Boolean is `set, grab the fourth token of the next line, exit the `for` and display.

Comment: @Magoo sounds good, but sorry, could you have an example code for me, so that I could modify it to suite what I need, sorry I am newbie here...

Comment: If you only want the `Throughput(MB/s)` figure from your `ntttcp.exe` commandline utility, do you even need the text file?

Comment: @Compo Yes I still need the text file as the test log, say that, it will be generated by a stress test script, not only one time will be executed but overnight, 5 minutes each cycle, so there will be many log files and they need be kept, for test script, I need to collect all performance numbers into a single file for quick review(so I don't need to open each log files to check the number), but, the original log still need be kept for further debugging.

Comment: So you are wanting to do this for multiple files then, what are they called? there must be a file naming pattern if this is being done in a scheduled cycle. It makes much more sense for a solution which reads all of them, rather than just one.

Comment: On DosTips.com they have this nice function that you can use to extract sections of a file. https://www.dostips.com/DtCodeCmdLib.php#Function.extractFileSection

Comment: Your example file above has only 49 lines, not 58, and `Throughput(MB/s)` is in line 32 instead of 43. So what you said (*There are total 58 lines...*) is wrong

Comment: @Compo Say that the test script would run the test for 5 minutes and then reboot the system, after booting into the OS, run the 5 minutes stress test again, and in loop for overnight. My test script is able to rename the test log and keep it for each cycle test, so that is no problem on multiple test log files, and, my test script will do the same thing on the test log when the 5 minutes stress test is finished and the test log is generated.

Comment: @Compo And that is what I said above, to capture the performance number to another text file for collecting all performance numbers by cycle tests, that is easy for me to quick overview all performance numbers when the overnight stress test is done.

Comment: @phuclv not really, the empty line also need be counted in since for the batch file even it is empty but is still a line. For the exmample content I post is just 100% copy and paste to here, that has included empty lines.

Comment: @JackyLee of course empty lines are counted. I copied what you posted above and pasted to a file and use `wc -l`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is a different and simpler approach. Instead of get the line *two lines below* `Throughput(MB/s)`, we can get the line *three lines above* `Throughput(Buffers/s)` that can be get via a single `findstr` command.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get a CR+LF (NewLine) variable
for /F %%a in ('copy /Z "%~F0" NUL') do set ^"NL=%%a^
%Don't remove this line%
^"

rem Get the appropriate line and get its 4th token
findstr "!NL!!NL!!NL!Throughput(Buffers/s)" LOM_1.log | for /F "tokens=4" %%a in ('more') do echo %%a
```

If you want to process several *.log files, just insert the `findstr ... | for ...` commands into a cycle that process the files.

**EDIT 2024/03/21:** *Get Errors number*

I was reading your request in the comments below [phuclv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78171267/778560) about get the "Errors" number. Get such a number is *very simple* in the Batch file:

If the `Packets Sent Packets Received Retransmits Errors Avg. CPU %` is the last section in the file, just do this:

```
for /F "tokens=4" %%a in (LOM_1.log) do set "Errors=%%a"
```

and that is it!  **`;)`**

Comment: @Compo: I am afraid you read not my answer...

Comment: Spotted it Aacini sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example of how I may try to achieve the task of retrieving those throughput values from each log file:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

PushD "P:\ath To\Log Directory" 2>NUL || Exit /B

(   For /F "Tokens=1-2 Delims=:" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe
     /INR "Throughput(MB/s)" "lom_*.log" 2^>NUL') Do Call :Sub "%%G" "%%H"
) 1>"%~dp0result.log"
Pause

PopD
EndLocal
GoTo :EOF

:Sub
Set /A "_l=%~2 + 1"
For /F "Tokens=4" %%I In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\more.com +%_l% "%~1"'
) Do Echo %%I& GoTo :EOF
```

You should obviously adjust the log file path on line four, and note that I have assumed the pattern of log file names is `lom_*.log`. The resulting file will reside in the same directory as your batch file.

Please note, if you are only processing one file per batch file run, rather than a directory full of them, you should only need to change `1>` to `1>>` on line eight.

Answer (score 0):

I misread your data somewhat, noting now that the required `Throughput(MB/s)` is token 6 and the required data is in token 4.

Nor sure whether you want to process multiple files - if not, the outer loop on `%%y` is not needed and substitute the filename for `%%y` in the remaining loop.

`%%b` will acquire token 4 and `%%c` token 6 in the processed lines

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following setting for the directory and filenames are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

(
FOR %%y IN ("%sourcedir%\q78165354*.txt") DO (
 SET "required="
 SET "grabnext="
 FOR /f "tokens=4,6delims= " %%b IN ('findstr /v /L /c:"=" "%%y"') DO IF /i "%%c"=="Throughput(MB/s)" (SET "grabnext=y") ELSE (
  IF NOT DEFINED required IF DEFINED grabnext SET required=%%b&ECHO %%b %%y
 )
)
)>"%outfile%"
GOTO :EOF
```

rem **Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

I used files named `q78165354*.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier in PowerShell, if the content isn't fixed then you can use this to match the 2<sup>nd</sup> line after `Throughput(MB/s)` and grab the last word:

```powershell
(sls -Co 0,2 'Throughput(MB/s)' -S file.txt).Context.PostContext.Split(' ')[-1]
```

If you want to get exactly the last token in line 43 then use this:

```powershell
(gc file.txt | select -Skip 42 -F 1).Split(' ')[-1]
```

`(some command).Split(' ')` will split the result of `some command` by space `' '` into an array then `[-1]` will get the last element in the array

*Full explanation and unaliased versions below*

---

Anyway your question doesn't seem to match the title. If you want to *the N<sup>th</sup>  line counting from the bottom* which is similar to `tail -<N> file.txt | head -1` on *nix then it's completely different. To get the 17th line from the last line simply use this

```powershell
 gc file.txt -Ta 17 | select -F 1
```

You can call it from cmd if you really can't avoid cmd like this:

```powershell
powershell -C "Get-Content file.txt -Tail 17 | Select-Object -First 1"
powershell -Command "(gc file.txt | select -Skip 42 -F 1).Split(' ')[-1]"
```

But just avoid cmd in new code, everything is easier in PowerShell

---

Here are the full unaliased version of the above commands

```bash
# Get the 43th line by skipping the first 42, then
# split the string by space ' ' and get the last word
(Get-Content file.txt | Select-Object -Skip 42 -First 1).Split(' ')[-1]

# Same as above but counting up skipping the last 16 lines instead
(Get-Content file.txt -Tail 17 | Select-Object -First 1).Split(' ')[-1]

# Find the line containing 'Throughput(MB/s)' and 2 lines of context after that,
# matching the string literally instead of regex, then extract the last word
# on the 2nd context line
(Select-String -Context 0,2 'Throughput(MB/s)' `
    -SimpleMatch file.txt).Context.PostContext.Split(' ')[-1]
```

Comment: additional question, if I want to get the "Errors" number, what the last value in following command should be: powershell (Select-String -Context 0,2 'Errors' ` -SimpleMatch LOM_1.log).Context.PostContext.Split(' ')[value]

Comment: @JackyLee it's just normal array indexing like in python or some other scripting languages. For array a then `a[i]` is the i-th element from the beginning if i >= 0 and from the end if i < =, so i = -1 takes the last element

Comment: phuclv Yes, but tried the -2 which to capture the last two element but failed, if I use the -1, then I will get the number of "Avg. CPU %"(last element as you said) but not "Errors" from my above example log in first post, so I just tried -2 to get the number of "Errors" but with no luck.

Comment: @JackyLee it's because the [normal `String.Split()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions?view=net-8.0) used in this case just allow a single delimiter character in a set. You need the `-split` operator if you want to split using multiple consecutive delimiter characters: `PS /Users/phluu> ((Select-String -Context 0,2 "Avg. CPU %" -SimpleMatch file.txt).Context.PostContext -split '\s+')[-4..-1]`. This will print the last 4 elements

Comment: @JackyLee Alternatively you can use the overload that allows trimming: `((Select-String -Context 0,2 "Avg. CPU %" -S file.txt).Context.PostContext.Split(' ', [StringSplitOptions]::TrimEntries + [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries))[-5..-2]`: this will print the last elements 2 to 5. Shorter method: `(-split (sls -Co 0,2 "Avg. CPU %" -S file.txt).Context.PostContext)[-4..-1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file, use `find` to determine the line number of `Througput(MB/s)` then add one to that to get the line number where your 4th token is the result:

```
@echo off & set "tput="
for /F "delims=[]" %%i in ('find /N "Throughput(MB/s)" "LOM_1.log"') do set /a ln=1+%%i
for /f "usebackq skip=%ln%tokens=4delims= " %%i in ("LOM_1.log") do if not defined tput set "tput=%%i"
echo %tput%
```

Append  `>> result.log` to the last line, if you require it to be stored in the file.